# Count number of true and false of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM {Products}
```

But the Products table has a boolean column `"IsInStock"`, and I want to count the number of products that have `IsInStock` at true and the number of products that have `InStock` at false so that the result of the query has this information. Do you know properly achieve this using SQL?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Oracle? boolean is invalid datatype as a table's column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below way -

```
select isinstoct, count(*)
from tablename
group by isinstoct
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [IsInStock]='True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [InStock],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [IsInStock]='False' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [OutOfStock]
FROM [Prodcuts]
```